# How to select a field based on the maximum number of rows

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel 4.2 and I have the following table that looks like this

```
 ID|chosen(boolean('0','1'))|subject|user_id
  1|1                       |cricket|2
  2|0                       |cricket|3
  3|1                       |rugby  |2
```

I would like to choose the `user_id` that has the most chosen rows or in other words the user that has the most 1s in their chosen column. So in this case user 2 would be the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like thus using query builder

```
$table = DB::table('table')
             ->select(array(DB::raw('count(User_ID) AS CountUser')))
              ->where('chosen', 1)
             ->orderBy('CountUser', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('User_ID')
             ->first();
```

Comment: thanks but I can't seem to view the result in my view. Can you help?

Comment: to pass to view you can do like this View::make('viewname',array('userDetails'  => $table));

Comment: to access data inside view you can do $table->CountUser

Comment: Sorry @kamlesh.bar I dont know what you mean by `userDetails`? I pass to the view by doing this: ` return View::make('secondhome', compact(array('table')));` and yes I do `$table->CountUser` but I only get the number 1s and not the user_id. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538520/how-to-display-a-user-determined-by-the-maximum-number-rows

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about laravel but you can use following sql for you query

```
 select user_id from(select max(count_ones), user_id from(select
 count(id) as count_ones,user_id from table_name where
 chosen = 1 group by user_id) as table1) as table2
```

here is sqlfiddle link for same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ca40/1

Edit:
use more efficient sql as suggested in other answers:

```
select count(id) as count_ones,user_id from table_name 
where chosen = 1 group by user_id order by count_ones desc limit 1
```