# How to display a user determined by the maximum number rows

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel 4.2 and I have the following table that looks like this

```
ID|chosen(boolean('0','1'))|subject|user_id
 1|1                       |cricket|2
 2|0                       |cricket|3
 3|1                       |rugby  |2
```

I would like to choose the user_id that has the most chosen rows or in other words the user that has the most 1s in their chosen column. So in this case user 2 would be the correct result.

I believe this is the answer

```
$table = DB::table('tablename')
         ->select(array(DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CountUser')))
          ->where('chosen', 1)
         ->orderBy('CountUser', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('user_id')
         ->first();
```

however **how do I display the user_id in my view?** For example:

```
{{$table->user_id}} //should give me '2'
```

Error message reads:

Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the count only. Try this

```
$table = DB::table('tablename')
     ->select(DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CountUser, user_id'))
      ->where('chosen', 1)
     ->orderBy('CountUser', 'desc')
     ->groupBy('user_id')
     ->first();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. I'm baffled!!

Comment: can you `dd($table)` after the query and show the result?

Comment: I get this `object(stdClass)#222 (1) { ["CountUser"]=> int(2) }` It counts the user which has the maximum number of 1s but for some reason I can't display that user

Comment: this must be a bug in Laravel!

Comment: try `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after the query and show result

Comment: thanks for your efforts Pawel however im unsure how to understand this very long complicated query log.